# Xcode 9.4 Build(Debug, Release) OK, But Archive fails with "directory not found for option.."

Tags: ios, xcode

The build was always success.
But, Archive was failed with "**directory not found for option -L**".

I searched this problem..And found this error is "Library link error".

So, I try to many things like this:

1. pod install
2. remove library, and re-add.
3. exit xcode
4. re-install xcode
5. reboot mac

But, nothing changed..

Please help me..

Here is my error msg:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/changbaeseo/Desktop/JESTINA.IOS/DerivedData/jestina/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/jestina_release/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FLAnimatedImage'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/changbaeseo/Desktop/JESTINA.IOS/DerivedData/jestina/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/jestina_release/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Toast'
ld: library not found for -lFLAnimatedImage
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And this is my library search path :

[library search path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3J0A.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

I execute my project with **.xcodeproj.**
But, execute project with **.xcworkspace**, ALL OK.